# Use Meijer-G function to represent the products of two Bessel functions

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions, hypergeometric-function

Here I define two modified Bessel functions of the second type: $K_{\mu }\sqrt{az}$, $K_{v} \sqrt{\frac {b}{z}}$. I am struggling to represent the products of these two modified bessel functions by Meijer-G functions. I try two ways. The fisrt way is to obtain the Meijer-G function representations of two bessel functions seperately and then multiply the two Meijer-G functions. Howerer, I can not found the Meijer-G function representation of  $K_{v} \sqrt{\frac {b}{z}}$. The second way is to directly obtain the Meijer-G function representation of the 
$K_{\mu }\sqrt{az}  K_{v} \sqrt{\frac {b}{z}}$.However, I am struggling to obtain the products by Meijer-G function. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: We have
$$K_\mu(\sqrt {a z}) =
\frac 1 2 G_{0, 2}^{2, 0} {\left( \frac {a z} 4 \middle|
 {- \atop \frac \mu 2, -\frac \mu 2} \right)}, \\
G_{p, q}^{m, n} {\left( \frac 1 z \middle| {\mathbf a \atop \mathbf b} \right)} =
G_{q, p}^{n, m} {\left( z \middle| {1 - \mathbf b \atop 1 - \mathbf a} \right)}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I am confused about if I can use the above formulas to derive the Meijer-G function representation of $K_{\mu } (\sqrt{\frac {a}{z}})$. Can you give me some advices?

Comment: The first formula is already sufficient (set $z = 1/z$), but you get a G-function of $a/(4 z)$. Then you can use the reflection formula (valid when the argument is not on the negative real axis) to get a G-function of $4 z/a$.